Is it possible to switch Termux's TTY and/or run command on another TTY via a bash-script?
I am trying to use the Termux Widget plugin which launches bash scripts as shortcuts on the homescreen. Everything seems to be in order except this one thing.
Say, there's a simple script which just starts mc or nano. I launch its shortcut from my homescreen. Then I minimize Termux to do something else.
Now, if I try to tap the same script/shortcut, it launches a new instance of the same program keeping a previous instance running.
As I figured, it launches to a different TTY each time. So that you get something like mc[1], mc[2], nano[3], mc[4], nano[5], etc. And you have to close every other instance to get to the first one.
I've tried to start commands directly to another TTY like that:
mc > 'dev/pts/27'

Permission denied on that.
Tried other things like changing shebang (as mentioned on the Termux-Widget Github page). No luck.
What I want is to launch mc, then minimize Termux, then launch nano, then go back to the same mc instance I've previously left, then go back to the same nano instance. All via the widget shortcuts (bash scripts in ~/.shortcuts). Like alt-tabbing and no typing to do that (or what's the point of widgets then).
And I guess the solution still is to manipulate TTY somehow from within the script. But there's no root and things work differently in Termux.
So, is it possible? What's the right way?
